# How do I print out a embed video?

Tags: theming

I have a paragraph which can either contain an image or a video. When I let the output just come out in `{{item.content}}` the actual youtube iframe is output. However when I start parsing things to detect if a video or image is there I seem to lose this functionality.

I can still manually grab the URL output. However, Drupal seems to have some inbuilt features that I'd like to preserve. For example, the Youtube link ends with *watch?* which Drupal knows to convert to *embed?*, otherwise Youtube will refuse the iframe connection.

This is what I'm currently doing.

```
{% for item in items %}
    <div class="leftItem">
        <h4>{{ item.content['#paragraph'].field_content_2_headline.value }}</h4>
        <p>{{ item.content['#paragraph'].field_content_2_content.value|raw }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightItem">
        {% if item.content['#paragraph'].field_content_2_media.0.entity.field_media_oembed_video is not empty%}
            {{  item.content['#paragraph'].field_content_2_media.0.entity.field_media_oembed_video.value }}
        {% else %}
            {% for list in item.content['#paragraph'].field_content_2_media.0.entity.field_media_image_1 %}
                <img src="{{ file_url(list.entity.fileuri) }}" alt="{{ list.value.alt }}">
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

If I just output `item.content['#paragraph'].field_content_2_media` when there's a video detected, I get an error that I'm trying to print a field list item.

Is there a way to reference the iframe functionality that Drupal seems to have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use field formatters instead of printing raw values. With Twig Tweak module it can be done as follows:

```
{{ item.content['#paragraph'].field_content_2_media|view }}
```

Answer (score 0):

this one works for me.
https://www.drupal.org/project/embed

Set your providers after adding the field

[image]